# ¿Se escribe Gobierno español o gobierno español?

Tags: ortografía

¿Se escribe **Gobierno** español o **gobierno** español? La verdad, que si es Gobierno de España, estoy seguro que todo debe de escribirse con inicial mayúsculas. Pero cuando uso el gentilicio no sé si **gobierno** ha de escribirse en mayúsculas o minúsculas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creo que lo que a vos te interesa es lo que dice al respecto la normativa de la R. A. E. En ese caso, la respuesta es que

> la palabra *gobierno* cuando significa ‘órgano superior del poder ejecutivo de un Estado o de una comunidad política’ **debe escribirse con mayúscula inicial**, y por tanto se aplica no solo cuando se refiere al órgano de un Estado soberano, sino también cuando es el de alguna de sus divisiones políticas, como regiones, comunidades autónomas, etc.

(Resaltado mío.)

Fuente: http://www.fundeu.es/recomendaciones-G-gobierno-con-inicial-mayuscula-785.html

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero sigo en las mismas, me refiero a cuando lleva el gentilicio. Otro ejemplo Gobierno de Canarias y (G) ó (g)obierno canario. Incluso ahora hasta me asalta la duda de si el gentilicio en este caso pudiera ponerse con mayúscula. Digo para el caso en que la segunda opción fuera correcta.

Comment: Es lo mismo, lo dice en el enlace, sea "Gobierno de Canarias", "Gobierno canario" o "Gobierno regional". Se refiere a un gobierno concreto, así que va en mayúscula.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, según la regla, va con mayúscula incluso en la frase “un Gobierno concreto”.

Comment: Gracias, a todos, acabo de encontrar esto que confirma la respuesta de usar la mayúscula. http://www.tex-tipografia.com/uso_minusculas_mayusculas_general.html

Comment: Fantástico. Entonces marcá la respuesta. Acá tenés otro link: http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=YBi3TbDdo2x5h1LDiqn

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero Si la respuesta te fue útil y solucionó tu duda, márcala como "aceptada" (accept answer). Puedes leer más información en la [ayuda](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score -3):

cuando digo "voy a cruzar el río" también me refiero a un río en particular y no lleva mayúscula. Por lo tanto no me satisface la explicación. Cuando hablo del gobierno regional no veo ninguna razón para usar mayúscula. Más bien veo una tendencia de la gente a ponerle mayúscula a las palabras que considera importantes. por ejemplo: director, gerente, etc., no llevan mayúscula, ni tampoco educación, ni tampoco independencia.